# В чем разница между int.Parse() и Convert.ToInt32()

Tags: c#

В чем разница между `int.Parse()` и `Convert.ToInt32()` в C# ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`int.Parse` преобразует строку (`string`) в `int` (если может).
`Convert.ToInt32` преобразует в `int` значение любого типа, из перечисленных [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx). boolean, double, float и т.д. А самое главное, может преобразовать экземпляр любого класса, реализующего `IConvertible`.

Если говорить о строках, то `Convert.ToInt32` внутри всё равно использует `int.Parse`. Но есть нюанс:

```
public static int ToInt32(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Int32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Для неинициализированной строки `int.Parse` выбросит исключение, `Convert.ToInt32` вернет 0.