# Пытаюсь понять методы Parse() и TryParse() и класс Convert

Tags: c#

Прочтал про эти 2 метода и класс на разных сайтах. С Convert все понятно, но с 2 -мя методами возикла сложность и в чем их отличия ?

Comment: Какая сложность у вас с ними сложность? Отличия? Посмотрите что они возвращают

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `int.Parse(string s)` пробует получить число из его строкового представления, в случае успеха возвращает число, иначе же бросает `FormatException`.

Метод `int.TryParse(string s, out int result)` проверяет, можно ли получить число из строки. Если это возможно - возвращает `true` и полученное число `out`-параметром, иначе возвращает `false` результатом и `default(int)` `out`-параметром.

Это если по-простому, на самом деле могут выбрасываться и другие исключения, в зависимости от того, что за строку вы передаете.

Пример использования второго метода:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
if (int.TryParse(s, out int i))
    Console.WriteLine("Число, увеличенное на 5: {0}", i + 5);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Введенная строка не являлась числом.");
```

Comment: Можно, простой пример TryParse

Comment: int.TryParse("10", out int result);

Comment: Благодарю, что подразумевается под default(int)

Comment: @Relonir, отредактировал ответ.

Comment: @Relonir, `default(ValueType)` возвращает значение по умолчанию для типа значений. Для `int` и всех остальных числовых типов это `0`.

Comment: Не хочу вас лишний раз беспокоить, но хотел спросить. TryParse чаще используется в условных операторах ?

Comment: @Relonir, он используется в тех случаях, когда попытка распарсить число из строки потенциально может оказаться неудачной. Если использовать `int.Parse` вместо него, то придется отлавливать исключение, а работа с исключениями намного более дорогостоящая в плане производительности, нежели простая проверка, которую можно сделать с `int.TryParse`.

Comment: Ваши слова помогли мне разобраться с этими двумя методами.Получается эти методы парсят строки в числа, TryParse используем, когда не уверены. А класс Convert, работает уже со всеми типами данных, верно ?

Comment: @Relonir, не могу ничего подробного сказать про этот класс, так как не знаком с ним толком. Но преобразования строки в число происходят с выбрасыванием исключения при неудаче, так что его использование ближе к int.Parse, если не эквивалентно ему.

Comment: @aa_talanin, Благодарю, т.е без разницы, что использовать при преобразовании строки в число, что ближе  к душе

Comment: @Relonir Почти все структуры типов в C# имеют `Parse` и `TryParse` методы (например дата, `DateTime.TryParse()`). Что касается "что же использовать", то я бы лучше использовал `if (.TryParse(value, out result)){}`, нежели что то другое, ибо если Exeption можно не допустить, то этим стоит воспользоваться! А по поводу что лучше `Convert` или `Parse`, то думаю [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/664394) хватит.

Comment: @aa_talanin, Если я все правильно понял, то Convert.ToInt32 в какой- то степени эквивалентно TryParse, также возвращяет 0.